# What is the range of the Mersenne Twister in Java?

Tags: java, range, mersenne-twister

I have the following program:

```
import java.util.*;
import cern.jet.random.engine.MersenneTwister;
import cern.jet.random.engine.RandomEngine;

public class printy{
    static RandomEngine val = new MersenneTwister( (int)System.currentTimeMillis() );
    System.out.println(var.toString());
}
```

What is the range in `var`? It is an integer of what size? Can it ever be 0?

According to the documentation, the seed cannot be 0, but the random INT could be zero. This is due to a (mathematical?) property of how the MersenneTwister is implied in Java?

Comment: Why would not you check the source yourself? PS: it also took me 10 seconds to google this https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/random/engine/MersenneTwister.html

Comment: @zerkms So, it is a number from -2147483648 to +2147483648

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [the API documentation](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/random/engine/MersenneTwister.html):

> MersenneTwister (MT19937) is one of the strongest uniform pseudo-random number generators known so far; at the same time it is quick. **Produces uniformly distributed int's and long's in the closed intervals [Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE] and [Long.MIN_VALUE,Long.MAX_VALUE], respectively, as well as float's and double's in the open unit intervals (0.0f,1.0f) and (0.0,1.0), respectively.**

Specifically...

- `Integers`: [-2147483648, 2147483647]
- `Long`: [-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807]
- `Float`: [0.0f, 1.0f]
- `Double`: [0.0, 1.0]

****Note:**** These are closed intervals (i.e. endpoints are included) per the documentation. When dealing with `Double` and `Float` values, "If one needs (0,1]-random numbers," the [article that introduced MT](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=272995) says: "simply discard the zeros."

Comment: I see. The seed cannot be 0, but the random INT could be zero. This was partially my confusion. `The seed can be any 32-bit integer except 0.`

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that confusion. Otherwise, you come off as someone who doesn't want to read documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to delete the question.